# Why does `around_save` or `after_touch` callbacks not execute on the creation of a new record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to have a method be executed anytime a record is created/updated.

I tried both `after_touch` and `around_save` and neither work for new record creation.

In fact `around_save` doesn't work when the record has been edited.

What callback can I use to update the record anytime it is saved (including on creation or whenever it is edited/updated)?

**Edit 1**

Here is some code:

```
after_save :set_firm_size, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.firm.present? }
after_save :set_score
after_save :check_or_set_max
after_save :calculate_weighted_score, :if => Proc.new { |c| c.score.present? }
```

The callback that is not being executed is the last one `calculate_weighted_score`.

```
def calculate_weighted_score
    # Sum products of weight & scores of each attribute
        weight = Weight.first
        score = self.score
        self.weighted_score = (weight.firm_size * score.firm_size) + (weight.priority_level * score.priority_level) + 
                (weight.inflection_point * score.inflection_point) + (weight.personal_priority * score.personal_priority) +
                (weight.sales_priority * score.sales_priority) + (weight.sales_team_priority * score.sales_team_priority) +
                (weight.days_since_contact * score.days_since_contact) + (weight.does_client_vote * score.does_client_vote) +
                (weight.did_client_vote_for_us * score.did_client_vote_for_us) + (weight.days_until_next_vote * score.days_until_next_vote) +
                (weight.does_client_vote_ii * score.does_client_vote_ii) + (weight.did_client_vote_ii_for_us * score.did_client_vote_ii_for_us) + 
                (weight.days_until_vote_ii * score.days_until_vote_ii)
        # self.update_attributes(:weighted_score => weighted_score)
end
```

This is what the log of an `edit` action looks like:

```
Started PUT "/clients/20" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-26 23:26:34 -0500
Processing by ClientsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"J172LuZQc5SPv8=", "client"=>{"name"=>"Jackie Boys", "email"=>"jack@welch.com", "phone"=>"1234567890", "firm_id"=>"2", "topic_ids"=>["1", "2", "10"], "personal_priority"=>"1", "last_contact"=>"2012-09-01", "vote"=>"1", "vote_for_user"=>"1", "next_vote"=>"2012-12-01", "vote_ii"=>"0", "vote_ii_for_us"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Update Client", "id"=>"20"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Client Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "clients".* FROM "clients" WHERE "clients"."user_id" = 1 AND "clients"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "20"]]
  Topic Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" 
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  Topic Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" WHERE "topics"."id" IN (1, 2, 10)
  Topic Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "topics".* FROM "topics" INNER JOIN "clients_topics" ON "topics"."id" = "clients_topics"."topic_id" WHERE "clients_topics"."client_id" = 20
   (0.8ms)  UPDATE "clients" SET "name" = 'Jackie Boys', "updated_at" = '2012-11-27 04:26:34.772771' WHERE "clients"."id" = 20
  Firm Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "firms".* FROM "firms" WHERE "firms"."id" = 2 LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  Score Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "scores".* FROM "scores" WHERE "scores"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  SalesTeam Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "sales_teams".* FROM "sales_teams" WHERE "sales_teams"."id" = 3 LIMIT 1
  PriorityLevel Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "priority_levels".* FROM "priority_levels" WHERE "priority_levels"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  UPDATE "scores" SET "client_id" = 20, "firm_size" = 102.0, "inflection_point" = 0.0, "sales_priority" = 1.0, "days_since_contact" = 86.0, "did_client_vote_for_us" = 1.0, "days_until_next_vote" = 5.0, "does_client_vote_ii" = 0.0, "did_client_vote_ii_for_us" = 0.0, "updated_at" = '2012-11-27 04:26:35.043986' WHERE "scores"."id" = 26
  Score Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "scores".* FROM "scores" WHERE "scores"."client_id" = 20 LIMIT 1
  Max Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "maxes".* FROM "maxes" WHERE "maxes"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "scores".* FROM "scores" WHERE "scores"."client_id" = 20 LIMIT 1
  Weight Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "weights".* FROM "weights" LIMIT 1
   (52.4ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/clients
Completed 302 Found in 505ms (ActiveRecord: 60.7ms)
```

Notice that what you should see is a statement that updates `client.weighted_score` but that doesn't appear in the logs.

When I added `self.update_attributes...` I got a `stack is too deep error`. The same thing would happen when I added `self.save` instead of `self.update_attributes`.

Comment: You have before_save and after_save as well, have you tried either of those?

Comment: Yes, but for whatever reason it doesn't work with new record creation.

Comment: Either of those should work with new record creation. There must be something else going on. Are you getting any errors or seeing rollbacks in the logs?

Comment: They both definitely work with new record creation. Suggest something else is the problem, and you should post some code.

Comment: I added some code and logs. @Beerlington not seeing any rollbacks in the logs on the `after_save` callback.

Comment: So the after_save callbacks *do* actually occur, just not the one you want. I see. Is the score actually present?

Comment: Yep, it is present....because one of the `after_save` callbacks right before this one, makes sure that it is set. I just checked and verified that it is indeed set.